# Cython's calculations are incorrect

Tags: python, cython, pi

I implemented the Madhava–Leibniz series to calculate pi in Python, and then in Cython to improve the speed. The Python version:

```
from __future__ import division
pi = 0
l = 1
x = True
while True:
    if x:
        pi += 4/l
    else:
        pi -= 4/l
    x = not x
    l += 2
    print str(pi)
```

The Cython version:

```
cdef float pi = 0.0
cdef float l = 1.0
cdef unsigned short x = True
while True:
    if x:
        pi += 4.0/l
    else:
        pi -= 4.0/l
    x = not x
    l += 2
    print str(pi)
```

When I stopped the Python version it had correctly calculated pi to 3.141592. The Cython version eventually ended up at 3.141597 with some more digits that I don't remember (my terminal crashed) but were incorrect. Why are the Cython version's calculations incorrect?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using `float` in the Cython version -- that's [single precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision)!  Use `double` instead, which corresponds to Python's `float` (funnily enough).  The C type `float` only has about 8 significant decimal digits, whereas `double` or Python's `float` have about 16 digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase speed, note that you can simplify the logic by unrolling your loop once, like so:

```
cdef double pi = 0.0
cdef double L = 1.0

while True:
    pi += 4.0/L - 4.0/(L+2.0)
    L += 4.0
    print str(pi)
```

Also note that you don't have to call print inside the loop - it is probably taking ten times longer than the rest of the calculation.

Answer (score -1):

How do you know when it's finished? Have you considered that the value for `pi` would oscillate about the true value, and you would expect that if you stopped the code at some point, you could have a value that is too high (or too low)?