# default float datatype in python and cython

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I ran into something interesting/weird or something that I am not able to figure out/comprehend.

Here it is,

**Code - 1: Python3.5**

```
a = 0.0;
print(type(a));
for i in range(10000):
    a += i;
print(a);
print(type(a));
```

**Output:**

```
<class 'float'>
49995000.0
<class 'float'>
```

**Code - 2: Cython0.26**

```
%%cython
cdef float a = 0;
print(type(a));
for i in range(10000):
    a += i;
print(a);
print(type(a));
```

**Output:**

```
<class 'float'>
49992896.0
<class 'float'>
```

I am running debian stretch (64 bit): I ran this codes in my jupyter notebooks after loading `%load_ext cython`.

I assume, the default for python is `float64`, since I run a 64bit OS and not explicitly setting to use `float32`. Assuming cython inherits the float datatype from python.

Why the outputs are different? And the difference seems to be large with large iterations - and this makes me think as truncation/rounding off of trailing bits. Could someone explain the reason behind and how to avoid?

**Edit:**
This question has been asked with a goal of understanding the difference between datatypes and hence applicable to wider audience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cython's calculations are incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730898/cythons-calculations-are-incorrect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C a float is generally [IEEE single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), aka float32.  While a float64 is IEEE double precision.  try:

```
cdef double a = 0;
```